# Razorpay Card Payment issue in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, razorpay, flutter-razorpay

```
 {data: {code: 100, message: {"error":{"code":"SERVER_ERROR","description":"We are facing some trouble completing your request at the moment. Please try again shortly.","source":"NA","step":"NA","reason":"NA","metadata":{}},"http_status_code":500}}, type: 1}
```

I have faced this type of issue when I try to payment in Razorpay payment integration

[razorpay_flutter_customui](https://pub.dev/packages/razorpay_flutter_customui)  package i am using